# Apple Magic Keyboard four key [4, r, f, v] problem

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, apple

I use MacBook Pro M1 chip 2020 model 16GB RAM, 256 SSD with an Apple magic keyboard.

[image: Apple magic keyboard]

The problem is, whenever I typed first time 4, r, f, v or 4, F, R, V it redirect me to the launchpad [image: LaunchPad] instead of typing those words as a text word. It also types the word too. If I type a second time it redirects me back to the type screen.

How to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. You can ask a MacOS question in the forum "Ask Different".

Comment: This ^^^. And very likely you have an hardware problem.

Comment: how to fix it though @ChanganAuto

Comment: Sure, Is there any way to move it on "Ask Different" @SadaharuWakisaka